# Problem mounting system partitions in rescue mode

Tags: partition, lvm, superblock

I have a serious problem.
Server crashed and not returned, disk problems.
I'm trying to mount `/dev/vg/root` partition
to access and remove the files but it's giving me a superblock error.

Until yesterday I was able to access it in read-only mode
using the command below.

```
mount -o ro,noload /dev/vg/root /mnt
```

But now not even this command works anymore because of the error.
I tried to recover the corrupted block without success.
The operating system know that all I need is access to the location -/dev/vg/root to remove our data.

Doing some checks at least the files are still allocated on the disk;
the problem is to access the location that is no longer visible for mounting.

```
mount /dev/vg/root /mnt
mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/vg-root, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

mount -o ro,noload /dev/vg/root /mnt
mount: /mnt: mount(2) system call failed: Stale file handle.
```

LVM used partition system

System where the server was installed: CentOS 6.9.

System I'm currently accessing in rescue mode.

```
Linux rescue 5.13.13 #1 SMP Thu Oct 28 09:11:58 UTC 2021 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

partition scheme (output from `lsblk`):

```
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0           7:0    0  2.9G  1 loop
sda             8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    2G  0 part
│ ├─md0         9:0    0    2G  0 raid1
├─sda2          8:2    0  2.7T  0 part
│ └─md1         9:1    0  5.5T  0 raid0
│   ├─vg-root 253:0    0  5.4T  0 lvm
│   └─vg-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm
└─sda3          8:3    0    1M  0 part
sdb             8:16   0  2.7T  0 disk
├─sdb1          8:17   0    2G  0 part
│ ├─md0         9:0    0    2G  0 raid1
├─sdb2          8:18   0  2.7T  0 part
│ └─md1         9:1    0  5.5T  0 raid0
│   ├─vg-root 253:0    0  5.4T  0 lvm
│   └─vg-swap 253:1    0    4G  0 lvm
└─sdb3          8:19   0    1M  0 part
```

Tried solutions like recovering bad blocks

```
sudo mke2fs -n /dev/xx

Failed attempt to recover bad blocks
sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/vg/root
```

Location I am trying to access,
which is where CentOS 6.9 is installed: `/dev/vg/root` 
The backup data I need is in this location.

Comment: so, what kind of filesystem is on /dev/vg/root?

Comment: does `dmesg` contain any additional info?

Comment: (1) You seem to be using LVM.  Please say so, in the ***text*** of the question.  (2) It might help if you told us *exactly* what operating system you are running.  Presumably Linux, but *which* Linux?  (3) Please give a bit more information on the things you tried.  (4) Can you explain what you mean by “the problem is to access the location that is no longer visible for mounting”? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: CentOS often uses `xfs`, not ext2/3/4. Check that. Try *appropriate* fsck. Tty booting from the live media. // raid0, serously?

Comment: Hello yes unfortunately raid 0.
It conforms to the partition scheme, it is using ext4.
I'm trying to recover the superblock to see if it resolves.